# Why do I get Twitter Highlights of people I no longer follow?

Tags: twitter

As the question states, I get Highlights like:

> **@SomeoneINoLongerFollow and 1 other follow**
>
> **Some User**
>   Some tweet that doesn't interest me

How do I stop getting these highlights (but still get the hightlights of people I do follow)?

Comment: I wonder if this is possible myself, awaiting an answer for this question.